# Ways to do String Addition inside Object Literal

Tags: javascript, string, reactjs

Can I do some string additions inside an object literal?

Chrome gives me the following error message if I do `height: 'calc(100% - ' + String(this.padding) + 'px * 2)'`.

> [ProjectContainer.js:15]  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'padding' of undefined

```
var styles = {
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        textAlign: 'left',
        padding: 10,
        height: 'calc(100% - ' + String(this.padding) + 'px * 2)',
        width: 'calc(100% - 10px * 2)',
        overflowY: 'scroll'
    }
}
```

However, if I make it as a function, no error message is displayed but the css seems not working. This may because the inline-style system does not call it as a function but variable.

```
var styles = {
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        textAlign: 'left',
        padding: 10,
        height: function() {return 'calc(100% - ' + String(this.padding) + 'px * 2)'},
        width: 'calc(100% - 10px * 2)',
        overflowY: 'scroll'
    }
}
```

What is the best way to make the height to be `'calc(100% - 10px * 2)'`?

Comment: You need to set it after you defined the object, you aren't creating an instance here. So `this` wont hold anything.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - He *is* creating an instance (of `Object`). @CasperLi - there's no JSON here: JSON is a string format for data interchange.

Comment: @nnnnnn You can't create an instance of something before you define it. The item isn't created inside `root` when properties are being defined. It's afterwards, by "here" I mean where they are trying to use `this`, maybe I wasn't clear on that.

Comment: I can create a variable `var paddingVal = 10;` before I create this instance and set `height: 'calc(100% - ' + paddingVal + 'px * 2)'` but this seems breaking my code structure. I want everything in one place.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - I was just being pedantic about your wording, because evaluating an object literal definitely creates an instance. And `this` will refer to *something* (perhaps the global object), just not the object being created. But you are right that you can't set the value of one property based on some other property within the same object literal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you can't use `this` to refer to your object literal as you are defining it. Instead it will refer to the global `this`, or the `this` in the current scope of the code. Basically you cannot use the properties of an object literal while you are still defining it, you will need to do so afterwards:

```js
var styles = {
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        textAlign: 'left',
        padding: 10,
        height: '',                     // Optional
        width: 'calc(100% - 10px * 2)',
        overflowY: 'scroll'
    }
}

styles.root.height = 'calc(100% - ' + String(styles.root.padding) + 'px * 2)';

console.log(styles);
```

Comment: Note while `height` is defined initially it's not necessary. Doing `styles.root.height` will create a `height` property if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
var styles = {
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        textAlign: 'left',
        padding: 10,

        width: 'calc(100% - 10px * 2)',
        overflowY: 'scroll'
    }, 
    init: function() {
       this.root.height = 'calc(100% - ' + String(this.root.padding) + 'px * 2)';
       delete this.init; 
       return this;
    },
}.init()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```js
var styles = (function() {
  var padding = '10';
  return {
    root: {
      display: 'flex',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      textAlign: 'left',
      padding: +padding,
      height: 'calc(100% - ' + padding + 'px * 2)',
      width: 'calc(100% - 10px * 2)',
      overflowY: 'scroll'
   }
})();
```

This makes use of a couple fun Javascript techniques such as:

- immediately invoked function expression ([IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression))
- [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) to coerce the string `'10'` into a number

This has the advantage of not only being done in a single expression, but also being easier to read and understand.

AND you could modify it so that the padding value could be passed in from the outside with almost no new work:

```js
var styles = (function(padding) {
  var padding = padding ? padding : '10';
  return {
    root: {
      display: 'flex',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      textAlign: 'left',
      padding: +padding,
      height: 'calc(100% - ' + padding + 'px * 2)',
      width: 'calc(100% - 10px * 2)',
      overflowY: 'scroll'
   }
})(padding);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `this` inside an object literal to reference a properly during declaration. `this` in JavaScript is used for function scope.

The example below shows a possible solution to your problem.
You basically define `padding` in a function scope and retrieve it within your object literal declaration.

> In most cases, the value of this is determined by how a function is
>   called. It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be
>   different each time the function is called. [More info on this here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

```js
function foo() {
 this.padding = 10; // declare it only once

  var styles = {
    root: {
      display: 'flex',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      textAlign: 'left',
      padding: this.padding,
      height: 'calc(100% - ' + String(this.padding) + 'px * 2)',
      width: 'calc(100% - 10px * 2)',
      overflowY: 'scroll'
    }
  };

  console.log(styles.root);

};

foo();
```